# BASH: bash completion function in a custom script

Tags: bash

How I can add existing function to a custom script?

`complete -F _known_hosts test.sh` - this works on the command line however when I tried to add this to my custom script it's not working as expected.

I also tried to source the file `. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

- System: CentOS7
- RPM: bash-completion-2.1-6.el7.noarch

**EDIT: Thu 16 Apr 08:07:11 BST 2015**

```
#!/binbash

. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
_known_hosts
...
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the completion code *inside* test.sh, and you want to have tab completion like `./test.sh foo<tab>` ? Or do you mean that test.sh implements a command-line interface for which you want to enable completion?

Comment: I want to put the completion code inside test.sh, another words `test.sh` should have the tab completion capability  for hosts

Comment: but the user's shell needs to know about the completion **before** the script executes, so the completion code cannot be bundled into the script. You need to get the user to source some initialization script that contains the completions

Comment: Please see my edit `_known_hosts` - I also tried to source the corresponding function in my script with no luck.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? As it stands now, if you add `complete -F _known_hosts test.sh` to something like your `.bashrc` it will use the function `_known_hosts` to provide tab completion when you execute `test.sh`. If you want to provide tab completion for a different script using the same rules, you can use  `complete -F _known_hosts otherscript.sh`